# TypeError - no implicit conversion of String into Integer in array Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make an area that outputs the following: `[@month, @monthly_count]` so that the complete output looks like this:  `[["January", 0], ["February", 0], ["March", 0], ["April", 2], ["May", 3], ["June", 19], ["July", 0], ["August", 0], ["September", 0], ["October", 0], ["November", 0], ["December", 0]]`

I'm currently getting the error that `TypeError - no implicit conversion of String into Integer:` on the line `@monthly_value_created[i] << @months[i]` below.

Here is my code:

```
@months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
@monthly_idea_value = [[0], [0], [0], [3], [35], [744], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]] 
#Array of arrays of integers isn't best, but unless it's causing the error I'm not worried about it right now.
#Bc the .flatten! method at the end fixes the output

      @monthly_value_created = Array.new(12){Array.new}
      i = 0
      12.times do |i|
        @monthly_value_created[i] << @months[i]
        @monthly_value_created[i] << @monthly_idea_value[i]
        @monthly_value_created.flatten!
        i += 1
      end
```

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip)

```
@months.zip(@monthly_idea_value).map &:flatten
```

You don't need to map and flatten, if `@monthly_idea_value` is an Array of integers, instead of an Array of Arrays.

Comment: Would this replace the entire iteration? from i=0 to i +=1?

Comment: Yes it does. And there are many mistakes in your code, which 2called-chaos has explained in detail. Read that, and also learn how loops work in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Might probably be more efficient to do:

```
@months.map.each_with_index do |month, index|
  [month, @monthly_idea_value[index][0]]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So you had two mistakes in your code.

First being incrementing `i` yourself while `#times` already passes the variable.

The second mistake you made is that you flattened the wrong thing (you only want to flatten the sub-array not the array structure you build.

```
@months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
@monthly_idea_value = [[0], [0], [0], [3], [35], [744], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]

@monthly_value_created = Array.new(12){Array.new}
12.times do |i|
  @monthly_value_created[i] << @months[i]
  @monthly_value_created[i] << @monthly_idea_value[i]
  @monthly_value_created[i].flatten!
end

=> [["January", 0], ["February", 0], ["March", 0], ["April", 3], ["May", 35], ["June", 744], ["July", 0], ["August", 0], ["September", 0], ["October", 0], ["November", 0], []]
```

Still fylooi's or Santhosh's approach is better and more ruby-ish :)